# Detect Volume button press EVEN when volume is max

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I want to detect when the volume button is pressed. I've try a lot of thing like add an Observer like

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVAudioSession.outputVolume), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

then Override :

```
override internal func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

But I want to trigger this function even if the sound is at max.

There is a way to do that without changing so sound to lower it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().observe(\.outputVolume) { [weak self] (audioSession, _) in
        <#code#>
    }
```

See https://github.com/andreamazz/SubtleVolume

Comment: Not working if the volume is already at its maximum.